# I need speed up the query existing code execution time is too much delay.modify possible to reduce the execution time. existing code is 1 min time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `mmyf_least_polling_booths_by_mandal_test`(IN `mandalid` INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        b.id as booth_id,
        b.name as booth_name,
        b.booth_no,
        b.location as booth_location,
        b.sorting,
        COUNT(lp.voter_id) as voted,
        COUNT(v.id) as total_voters,
        (COUNT(v.id) - COUNT(lp.voter_id)) as not_voted,
        (CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(v.id) IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN COUNT(lp.voter_id) IS NULL THEN 0 
            WHEN COUNT(lp.voter_id) = 0 THEN 0 
            WHEN COUNT(v.id) = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ROUND((COUNT(lp.voter_id) / COUNT(v.id)) * 100) 
        END) as voting_per

    FROM mmyf_live_polling lp
    RIGHT JOIN mmyf_voters v ON v.id = lp.voter_id AND v.mandal_id = mandalid
    RIGHT JOIN booths b ON b.id = v.booth_id

    WHERE 
        v.mandal_id = mandalid

    GROUP BY v.booth_id

    ORDER BY voting_per ASC;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

## creation for tables

```
CREATE TABLE `booths` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ac_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booth_no` smallint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sorting` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_voters` int(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `mmyf_voters` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_name_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=Father;2=Husband;3=Guardian',
  `mobile` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booth_no` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_no` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_house_no` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incharge_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=M;2=F;3=Other',
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ward_no` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mandal_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `booth_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_no` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_name_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_name_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `psb_building_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tahsil_name_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postoff_pin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pcname_v1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered` tinyint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `voter_update_count` tinyint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `voter_survey_count` tinyint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_verify` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified_status` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified_by` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `mmyf_live_polling` (
  `id` int(45) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `voter_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_no` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mandal_id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `village_id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booth_no` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ward_no` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `party_id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `religion` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incharge_id` int(125) DEFAULT NULL,
  `incharge_user_id` int(125) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caste_id` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT'enter code here',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I need execution time is reduce for msec.

Comment: Add table definitions as text so we can see the indexes, add an explain so we can see what the optimiser is doing rewrite code to left joins for understandibility.

Comment: The query is logically incorrect. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, fix the query. Use LEFT joins (reorder source tables).

Comment: booths table has id,booth_no,name,ac_id mmyf_voters has id,name,ac_id,mandal_id,village_id,booth_id,booth_no,mmyf_live_polling has voter_id,ac_id,mandal_id,village_id,booth_no,ward_no

above is the table columns in that mmyf_voters has 5 lacs data..

Comment: Please edit the question to include the result of show create table tablename for all three tables and run explain select...ORDER BY voting_per ASC; (ie the query on the procedure). Also what's a lac?

Comment: @P.Salmon I would guess _lac_ is an alternative transcription of _lakh_. In the Indian numbering system, _lakh_ is 100 thousand, and _crore_ is 10 million. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system So I think the OP's table has on the order of 500,000 rows.

Comment: @Bill Karwin while you are on translation services what's a mandal?

Comment: Depends on the context, but I have read it's a term for a local administrative subdistrict used in some Indian states.

Answer (score 0):

The column `mmyf_live_polling.voter_id` is not the same data type as the column `mmyf_voters.id` to which you join it. I suggest altering the column so it is the same data type.

```
ALTER TABLE mmyf_live_polling MODIFY voter_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED;
```

Then add some indexes to optimize the joins.

```
ALTER TABLE mmyf_voters ADD KEY (mandal_id);

ALTER TABLE mmyf_live_polling ADD KEY (voter_id);
```

Of course with such a large number of rows in the table, it will take a while. I hope you have a development environment with a smaller copy of the table containing test data. Test there first.